# Flexbox: Unwanted line break

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There should be 3 DIVs in a row. For some reason, a newline occurs after the second DIV. There should be enough space, as each DIV only has a width of 33%. So why is this line break happening?

The result should look like this:

[image]

Here's my current code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.third {
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #555;
  flex-basis:calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">


    <div class="third">third</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>

    <div class="third">third</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>

 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider margin within the calculation of `flex-basis`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px solid;
}

.third {
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #555;
  flex-basis:calc(100%/3 - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">


    <div class="third">third</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>

    <div class="third">third</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>

 
</div>
```